# How add select in list without join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't need to join in a whole table, but just want a value from the table returned in my select list (but other tables are joined for other items).  It's giving me an error...incorrect syntax near select

```
select c.id as caseId
,sc.date
,select id from Queues where name = 'BB' as queueId --incorrect syntax near select..but just need this id without joining with other data
FROM
dbo.Cases c 
INNER JOIN Extensions sc on sc.id=c.id

Cases:
id     area     user
1      here     Michele
2      there    George

Extensions:
id    subArea    line
1     hereThere  b
2     ThereHere  c
```

I'm having trouble searching online for this.

Comment: What is wrong with joining with Queues and getting the id? Also, please specify the SQL flavor you are using.

Comment: If that sub-select returns zero or 1 row at most, then it's a "scalar subquery" and must be enclosed in parenthesis. If it returns more than one row the query will crash.

Comment: Microsoft sql server. Queue names don't join to cases. I just need to look one up so no join needed.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Also tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: @Michele Oh, then you can store the id in a variable `DECLARE @qId INT = (select id from Queues where name = 'BB')` and return it in your Select. I assume you get only one id for that name. If not, either use `TOP 1` or clarify the requirement since what you want is not clear (i.e. which Queue id to use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the *scalar subquery* returns one row at most, you can enclose it between parenthesis, as in:

```
select c.id as caseId
,sc.date
,(select id from Queues where name = 'BB') as queueId
FROM
dbo.Cases c 
INNER JOIN Extensions sc on sc.id=c.id
```

If the scalar subquery returns more than one row the whole query will crash.